Are there structures or systems that can have a high angular momentun that are not made by protons and/or neutrons?
Cosmic structures such as neutron stars, white dwarfs or black holes can have high amounts of angular momentum (high spin velocities). However, these are all made by protons and neutrons (black holes are not technically made of these, but they come from structures composed by them).
Proton may decay and black holes evaporate due to Hawking radiation. Isolated particles such as cosmic rays are "redshifted" in time due to the expansion of the universe and tend to be at rest.
So, as angular momentum does not redshift (and therefore, the energy associated with it does not decay as well), is there some kind of structure or system that can have a high amount of angular momentum (or any other kind of property associated with energy that does not redshift and endures in time) that are stable and do not "evaporate" or decay (like black holes or maybe protons)?

Black holes may theoretically be formed from events other than that involving baryonic matter see kugelblitz. Also a system may lose angular momentum via gravitational radiation.

@Triatticus sorry with angular momentum I meant spin (which would not be lost to gravitational waves, unlike orbits). Also, even a kugelblitz black hole would still evaporate, so it is not considered in my question

Protons may decay, but angular momentum is still conserved, so what is your objection to cold neutron stars without magnetic fields?

My question is whether there is some kind of structure that a) would not decay (in the sense that we don't have any theory framework in which they would decay in principle) and b) can have a high amount of angular momentum that does not diminish. Neutron stars (and every other large object like white dwarfs or black holes) could decay according to proton decay. We don't know for sure, but we have theories that predict it. I was asking for some kind of structure that is not predicted to decay by any of our known theories (even if we don't know if they are experimentaly correct) @ProfRob

"Since angular momentum does not redshift". I don't think this is true. At least, the Newtonian definition of angular momentum is not an invariant.

@ProfRob as far as I know that is true for angular momentum in orbits (orbits decay via gravitatonal waves emission). But I am talking about spin or rotation (like the Earth's rotation)

If an object is receding from you it will appear to spin slower.

but does the object actually lose spin? Would an alien living in a receding planet measure a decreasing spin rate? @ProfRob
